# import ics file, create event in iOS

Tags: ios, import, icalendar

I found a few questions on SO and even with answers but not one of them helped me solve the problem.
I have ICS file

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:1.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20120719T110000
DTEND:20120719T120000
LOCATION:26 - 12 Hyde Way, Welwyn Garden Centre, Hertfordshire, AL7 3UQ
DESCRIPTION:You are going to be interviewed by: Paddy Allum - Group Health & Safety Manager and Heather Hughes - Group Training Manager
SUMMARY:CreativeSchool Group Plc
PRIORITY:3
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

I tried to import it when it's local file:

```
NSString * path = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"appointment.ics"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:targetURL];
```

and from external url:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com/appointment.ics"]];
```

and load directly to UIWebView but all failed. Tried both in simulator (which doesn't have Calendar app) and on device. When tried open external URL I was getting an alert "Impossible to subscribe... something blahblah"

Can anyone give me a clue if it's possible at all? Apple announced iOS 4.2 was going to support this stuff.